# PrimeFaces bar chart: hide color in legend

Tags: primefaces, chart.js, legend

PrimeFaces bar chart: how to hide color in legend?

One data series but each bar has different color.

```html
<p:barChart model="#{bean.model}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that shown right here in the Demo showcase? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/bar/bar.xhtml

```java
List<String> bgColor = new ArrayList<>();
        bgColor.add("rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)");
        bgColor.add("rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)");
        barDataSet.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
```

Comment: The legend uses the color of the first bar. I think that's the issue / question.